# Trying to make my code look like the cafe wall illusion

Tags: java

Here's what I have:
[image: Here's what I have]

Here's my code for it:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class CafeWall {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(650, 400);
        panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();

        // rows
        row(g, 20, 4, 0, 0);
        row(g, 30, 5, 50, 70);
        // grids
        grid(g, 25, 4, 10, 150, 0);
        grid(g, 25, 3, 250, 200, 10);
        grid(g, 20, 5, 425, 180, 10);
        grid(g, 35, 2, 400, 20, 35);

    }
    // size is the pixel width/height of a square.
    // multiples is the number of black/white pairs to draw.
    // x,y are the screen position of the top left corner.
    public static void row(Graphics g, int size, int multiples, int x, int y) {
        for (int i = 0; i < multiples; i++) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(x + size * 2 * i, y, size, size);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(x + size + size * 2 * i, y, size, size);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawLine(x + size * 2 * i, y, x + size + size * 2 * i, y + size);
            g.drawLine(x + size + size * 2 * i, y, x + size * 2 * i, y + size);
        }
    }
    // size is the pixel width/height of a square.
    // multiples is the number of black/white pairs to draw.
    // x,y are the screen position of the top left corner.
    // offset is the amount to offset by.
    public static void grid(Graphics g, int size, int multiples, int x, int y, int offset) {
        for (int i = 0; i < multiples * 2; i++) {
            row(g, size, multiples, x + (offset * i), y + (size * i) + (2 * i));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what I need it to look like. I feel like I've tried everything.

[image: cafe wall illusion]

Comment: First of all, never call `.getGraphics()` on a Swing component and then use it to draw with. Instead override your drawing JPanel's paintComponent method. Your actual problem looks to be more of a math calculation problem than a true programming problem.

Comment: Agree with the advice to .getGraphics , But I wouldn't think that math problems in the context of programming are necessarily off-topic.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach: I didn't say that the math question necessarily made the off-topic. It is off-topic in my mind for being too broad and unclear, for not doing enough prior divide-and-conquer work. The OP needs to break the big problem down into its constituent steps and then try to solve them one at a time, in isolation if need be. Without doing this first, the question almost becomes a request for work.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't pose my question better. This is my first one on here. I need to indent the rows to the left. I figured you were all geniuses and would know this like the back of your hand. I didn't know what to expect. I'm sorry.

Comment: Yeah don't sweat, it's hard when beginning to even get a grip on where to start asking questions, and how best to ask, just keep trying to improve :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@drifter265 I want to answer, but I also want you to learn, as this seems like a starter level project designed for teaching.

So rather then provide an answer directly, I'm instead going to show you where your error is, by explaining what your current program is currently doing.

```
// size is the pixel width/height of a square.
// multiples is the number of black/white pairs to draw.
// x,y are the screen position of the top left corner.
// offset is the amount to offset by.
public static void grid(Graphics g, int size, int multiples, int x, int y, int offset) {
    for (int i = 0; i < multiples * 2; i++) {
        row(g, size, multiples, x + (offset * i), y + (size * i) + (2 * i));
    }
}
```

This code here is relatively straight forward.

it's currently looping from 0 increment by 1, for the total number of black and white squares you wish to draw. (stopping before multiples*2 which is correct for starting at 0)

every time it loops, it calls row.

it's roughly equivalent to

```
        row(g, size, 2, x + (offset * 0), y + (size * 0) + (2 * 0));
        row(g, size, 2, x + (offset * 1), y + (size * 1) + (2 * 1));
        row(g, size, 2, x + (offset * 2), y + (size * 2) + (2 * 2));
        row(g, size, 2, x + (offset * 3), y + (size * 3) + (2 * 3));
```

(It's creating twice as many rows, as black columns)

The problem that you have, is that your offset is always growing, rather then zig zagging back and forth.

```
where x = 0, and offset = 10
        rowoffset = x + (offset * 0) = 0
        rowoffset = x + (offset * 1) = 10
        rowoffset = x + (offset * 2) = 20
        rowoffset = x + (offset * 3) = 30
```

but what you want, is

```
where x = 0, and offset = 10
        rowoffset = 0; // where i == 0
        rowoffset = 10 // where i == 1
        rowoffset = 0  // where i == 2
        rowoffset = 10 // where i == 3
```

A common way to implement branching behavior, which depends on a decision to be made is by using an if statement.

So instead of passing `x+offset*i` to row, you could instead introduce a variable there, that depends on whether i is odd or even.

A common method of working out whether an integer is odd or even, is to use the [remainder operator (`%`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3), passing in the number 2. (however care must be made when using negative values on either side)

```
0%2 == 0
1%2 == 1 
2%2 == 0
3%2 == 1
~~~
8%2 == 0
9%2 == 1
```

So you can now either use math, or if statements in order to make your zig zag like pattern.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you for taking the time to explain that for me. I didn't even think of using the modulo operator.

Comment: How did you guys know intuitively to use the modulo operator?

Comment: Experience, modulo is best used when you have a simple repeating pattern, and don't need to mess around with negative numbers or overflow.

Comment: Also it's an "odd/even" test / problem. What your real question is for that part of the code is "How do I change behavior based on a odd or even number"

Comment: @drifter265: don't forget to up-vote **both** answers. You've accepted one, good, but since both were helpful, you should also up-vote both of them. But also you didn't answer my prior question -- what happens to your GUI graphics when you minimize and then restore your running program?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I minimized and restored it. Nothing happened. I don't think I understand your question. I only started programming last week and my knowledge with the graphics of computers is very minimal. I'm sorry I can't be more help. Also, for some reason, it's not accepting my up votes. Ryan The Leech, Your question is very good lol. I have to think about it. Thank you guys all so much for your devoted help!

Comment: @drifter265: when you use `.getGraphics()` to draw with, any drawings will disappear when you minimize and restore a GUI. This is one of several reasons to avoid doing this and to instead override a JPanel's `paintComponent` method. Also (and again), please do up-vote both answers, since as it stands, I'm the only one who has done this so far.

Answer (score 1):

You constantly add to the x parameter in your grid method.

If you only want to move every second row, you can use a modulo operation like this:

```
public static void grid(Graphics g, int size, int multiples, int x, int y, int offset) {
    for (int i = 0; i < multiples * 2; i++) {
        row(g, size, multiples, x + offset * (i % 2), y + (size * i) + (2 * i));
    }
}
```

Comment: @drifter265: what happens when you minimize your program and then restore it?